# Increase processing time serverside datatable

Tags: php, jquery, datatable, ini

I am trying to increase processing speed of My website while using datatable, I have changed memory_limit to 400M also increased max_execution_time.Website's load time is 2-3 seconds.

My website is hosting on Godaddy's Window's Server.(Shared Hosting)
Here is my code-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    </head>
    <body>

    <table class="table table-bordered data-table table-striped" id="data-table">
        <thead><tr><th>Report ID</th><th>Report Title</th><th class="tabhead">Price</th></tr></thead>

        <tfoot><tr><th>Report ID</th><th>Report Title</th><th class="tabhead">Price</th></tr></tfoot>
    </table>

    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/matrix.tables.js"></script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Jquery-matrix.tables.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('#data-table').DataTable( {

    destroy: true,
    stateSave: true,
    "deferRender": true,
    "pageLength": 100,
    "paging": true,
    //"orderClasses": false,
    "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "https://www.blahblah.com/server_processing.php",

    });
});
```

server_processing.php

```
<?php

$table = 'tbl';

$primaryKey = 'id';
$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'id', 'dt' => 0 ),
    array( 'db' => 'title',  'dt' => 1 ),
    array( 'db' => 'price',   'dt' => 2 ),
);
$sql_details = array(
    'user' => '****',
    'pass' => '****',
    'db'   => '****',
    'host' => '****'
);
require( 'ssp.class.php' );

echo json_encode(
    SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
);
?>
```

also added ssp.class.php

When I try to search in datatable search box it is taking min 20-30 seconds to respond.
Is there anything wrong with my code?

What else should I do to increase response time for this website?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is your database optimized ? index ? Key ? foreign key ?

Comment: Yes my database is optimized. It doesn't have more tables though.